# Why does the readImageLists can't read my image list in txt file?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, opencv3.0

When I use vs2013+opencv3.0 to run my project,I found the function "imread" can't read image unless there is just one line in the image_list.There are someone says it's because the "readImageList" function can't recognize the line break in txt document, I don't know how to do.Does anyone can solve this problem?

```
string model_path = "E:\\images\\opencv3.0\\opencv_contrib-master\\modules\\dpm\\samples\\data\\inriaperson.xml";
string image_dir = "E:\\images\\opencv3.0\\DPMopencv\\INRIAPerson";
string  image_list = "E:\\images\\opencv3.0\\DPMopencv\\INRIAPerson\\Test\\pos1.lst";
if( model_path.empty() || image_dir.empty() )
{
    help();
    return -1;
}

vector<string> imgFileList;
if ( !readImageLists(image_list, imgFileList) )
    return -1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < imgFileList.size(); i++)
{
    double t = (double) getTickCount();
    vector<DPMDetector::ObjectDetection> ds;

    string imageFile = image_dir + "\\" + imgFileList[i];
    Mat image = imread(imageFile);

    frame = image.clone();

    if (image.empty()) {
        cerr << "\nInvalid image:\n" << imgFileList[i] << endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Unless the list file was created in linux and you're reading it from windows, there shouldn't be any problem. Please verify that the full path to the image is correct before calling `imread`. Also, post the code as _formatted code_ and not as an image. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by changing the way to read image_list file:

`string model_path = "E:\\images\\opencv3.0\\opencv_contribmaster\\modules\\dpm\\samples\\data\\inriaperson.xml";`

```
if (model_path.empty())
{
    help();
    return -1;
}
 Mat frame;
string Image;
ifstream fin("E:\\images\\opencv3.0\\DPMopencv\\INRIAPerson\\pos.lst");

for (int i = 1; i <= 100 && getline(fin, Image); i++)
{
    double t = (double)getTickCount();
    vector<DPMDetector::ObjectDetection> ds;
       Image = "E:\\images\\opencv3.0\\DPMopencv\\INRIAPerson\\" + Image;
         Mat frame = imread(Image);
         Mat image = frame.clone();
         imshow("init", frame);
    if (Image.empty()) {
        cerr << "\nInvalid image:\n" << endl;
        return -1;
}
```